# Disable runtime error dialog in Android

Tags: android

When I run app with vitamio library in android N, it generates a popup every time (libffmpeg.so file error dialog). When i minimize the app or onStop called in activity. It was working fine in previous android versions.

I only need to disable that dialog. Video is playing fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWrfp.png)

Comment: Can you post the code for onStop?

Comment: Sonam, don't forget to share your related code when you ask a question on SO.

Comment: only called video.pause() and that pause is a library method. That is the error from libffmpeg.so file and that is use by Vitamio library.